# Run functional tests in Bamboo Elastic instance (Amazon x86_64 server(linux)(elastic image))

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bamboo

I am stuck attempting to run functional tests in a Bamboo elastic instance. I want to run my functional tests in Bamboo Amazon x86_64 server. In Amazon Linux: Default Image EBS i386 (linux) elastic instance, I installed Firefox 17.0.1 version to run my functional tests. From my local machine I wish to run the functional tests in Elastic instance as part of my build every night. However, I am getting configuration errors.
In the functional tests pom file:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>xvfb</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>xvfb</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <display>:2.0</display>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>start-server</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <background>true</background>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

To run headless selenium tests in Elastic instance, I started the `Xvfb`(X-virtual frame buffer) from build in pom file and set the Display to :2.0
My test class setup to run Firefox:

```
    private WebDriver driver;
    @Before 
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In Elastic instance this is how I did my configuration:

Installed firefox version 17.0.1.
Also installed Xvfb server in Elastic instance using command `yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` to set the Display varaible to :2.0, in the command line: `export DISPLAY=:2.0`

Then when I type Firefox in the command line it shows
`error:cannot open display=:2.0`

All is set to run my tests.

When I run my tests, Selenium server is v2.40.0 
It is showing `Xvfb` is started. I checked in elastic instance to see whether `Xvfb` is running or not using `ps aux | grep -i xvf.` It is running as Xvfb :2.0

Everything is going well but when it comes to the test it can't find Firefox.

```
[INFO] Starting Xvfb...
    [INFO] Using display: :2.0
[INFO] Using Xauthority file: /tmp/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/Xvfb5480072413528139773.Xauthority
Deleting: /tmp/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/Xvfb5480072413528139773.Xauthority
xauth:  creating new authority file /tmp/AT-RSTEN-      JOB1/Xvfb5480072413528139773.Xauthority
Created dir: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/target/selenium
Launching Xvfb
    Waiting for Xvfb...
[INFO] Redirecting output to: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/target/selenium/xvfb.log
Xvfb started
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:start-server (default) @ functionalTests ---
Launching Selenium Server
Waiting for Selenium Server...
    [INFO] Including display properties from: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/target/selenium/display.properties
[INFO] User extensions: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/target/selenium/user-extensions.js
    INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] Java: Oracle Corporation 23.25-b01
    INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] OS: Linux 3.4.48-45.46.amzn1.x86_64 amd64
    INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] v2.40.0, with Core v2.40.0. Built from revision 4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e
    INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
   INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer] Version Jetty/5.1.x
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/,/]
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@435879e8
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener] Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
   INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@42ac76c0
   INFO - Checking Resource aliases
Selenium Server started
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default) @ functionalTests ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.bob.LoginTestSelenium
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

at    
                org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at      org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:96)
    at com.bob.LoginTestSelenium.setUp(LoginTestSelenium.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)


Results :
Tests in error: 
  testWrongUsernameCorrectPassword(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testWrongUsernameCorrectPassword(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium)
  testLogin(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testLogin(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium)
  testRememberMeFunctionLogoutLogin(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testRememberMeFunctionLogoutLogin(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium)
  testRememberMeFunctionChangeUsername(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testRememberMeFunctionChangeUsername(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium)
  testWrongPassword(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testWrongPassword(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium)
  testRememberMeFunctionNotTicked(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testRememberMeFunctionNotTicked(com.bob.LoginTestSelenium)
  testAddingActionsToAnAlertUpdatesTheAnimalHistory(com.bob.EstrusAlertsTestSelenium):      Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
  testAddingActionsToAnAlertUpdatesTheAnimalHistory(com.bob.EstrusAlertsTestSelenium)

Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 14, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6:36.882s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 27 15:23:35 UTC 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default) on project functionalTests: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Deleting: /tmp/AT-RSTEN-JOB1/Xvfb5480072413528139773.Xauthority
Failing task since return code of [/opt/maven-3.0/bin/mvn --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/AT-RSTEN-JOB1 clean install] was 1 while expected 0
Parsing test results...
Finished task 'Maven 3.x'
Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
Finalising the build...
Stopping timer.
Build AT-RSTEN-JOB1-82 completed.
Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
    Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
All post build plugins have finished
Generating build results summary...
Saving build results to disk...
Indexing build results...
Finished building AT-RSTEN-JOB1-82.
```

Can anyone help me regarding this?
Am I missing some configuration for Firefox to be set in elastic instance? 
What is "`failed to connect to Firefoxbinary(usr/bin/firefox)`"? Where must I specify this? Do I need to add this Firefox binary in functional tests setup to get running Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here.
Lets try this one step at a time.

firstly, log into your ec2 instance and run the following commands..

Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x768x24 &

export DISPLAY=:1

now try to run firefox from the command line. let me know if this works without giving you an error.

Comment: Btw, i know you think it is the binary location that is the issue and you could be right but I want to make sure this bit works before we do anything else.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The commands you said are working fine for me in command line. firefox is running from command line. Virtual frame buffer is also running. Still I am getting the error i listed above in my question. Can you suggest me another solution for this one.

Comment: ya, you are seeing an error saying 'no display specified' in your log output above but we know that error doesnt display when you ran those three commands above. So the logical explanation is that your bamboo user doesnt have a DISPLAY variable set in a new instance. So edit the user's .bashrc file and export the display to :2 in there and rerun your test suite then. (I assume you have EBS or else you would need to reimage with the change)

Comment: I done as you said. As a bamboo user i added export DISPLAY=:2.0 in .bashrc file This is my .bashrc file now.                                                         #. bashrc

     # Source global definitions
     if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 . /etc/bashrc
     fi
    export DISPLAY=:2.0
    # User specific aliases and functions                                Still I am getting same error when i run my functional tests. Also added in the ec2-user .bashrc file same line.